# Save Image File using MediaStore API

Tags: android, kotlin, mediastore, android-contentresolver

How can we save image file in **DCIM** folder using MediaStore API ?

```
private fun savePhotoToExternalStorage(displayName: String, bmp: Bitmap): Boolean {
    val imageCollection = sdk29AndUp {
        MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
    } ?: MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "$displayName.jpg")
        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH, bmp.width)
        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.HEIGHT, bmp.height)
    }
    return try {
        contentResolver.insert(imageCollection, contentValues)?.also { uri ->
            Log.e("file path", File(uri.path.toString()).absolutePath)
            contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri).use { outputStream ->
                if (!bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, outputStream)) {
                    throw IOException("Couldn't save bitmap")
                }
            }
        } ?: throw IOException("Couldn't create MediaStore entry")
        true
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        false
    }
}
```

in above code, my file is saved in **Pictures** Directory. but i want it in **DCIM** Directory for both above and below SDK version 29.

Comment: You have to use column .RELATIVE_PATH for Q+.

Comment: @blackapps yes, its done in Q+. but what about below Q ?

Comment: I dont see you doing so. Please adapt your code for as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this way to save image

```
fun saveImnage(
            context: Context,
            bmap: Bitmap,
            name: String
        ): File? {
            val file = File(
                context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM),
                "$name.jpeg"
            )
            val outStream: FileOutputStream
            try {
                outStream = FileOutputStream(file)
                bmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream)
                outStream.flush()
                outStream.close()
            } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            return file
        }
```

hope it may help you

Comment: i already mentioned, using MediaStore API.

Comment: the above code supports all version and best,  if you dont want then please try this  in existing with validation of Q and below         
final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);